# Embryo development terms

Tags: development, embryology

I'm trying to couple the following terms: 
cytoplasmic determinants, induction, positional information, hox genes, pattern information, morphogenisis, determination and differentiation.

I hope someone can explain me the connection between these terms,

thankyou,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt go back to definitions I say (as I am now).

**cytoplasmic determinants**: regulatory molecules located in specific distributions around egg cytoplasm

**Induction**: process by which the presence of one tissue influences the development of others

**positional information**, signals cells about its relative position to other cells.
hox genes

**Differentiation**: the process of a cell becoming a specialized type of cell through regulated gene expression

**Determination**: process by which portions of the genome are selected for expression in different embryonic cells

**Pattern formation** (aka morphogenesis) → events that determine the spatial organization of an embryo

**Hox genes** establish anterior posterior axis and regulate gene expression.

I would change, 
cytoplasmic determinants → differentiation via determination → pattern formation (rather than information)
morphogen lead to pattern information (since these are the signals)
hox genes → morphogens → pattern information → pattern formation